# Symfony Deployment Path /public/-Folder problem

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, path, public

I am currently in the process of putting my first Symfony-project online. Everything works except the correct Routing. So i can see my website with the link "www.mywebsite.de/mywebsite/public/"
*Before I created the htaccess file the link was "www.mywebsite.de/mywebsite/public/index.php"*

When i want to reach the Login-Side it directs me to the path "www.mywebsite.de/login/ but there is the Error 404 because of the wrong path... The path "www.mywebsite.de/mywebsite/public/login" would work.

So my goal is that every side is available with  the address "www.mywebsite.de/..."
I know from my research (yes i already read the [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html))  that i should move the htaccess rules to the main Apache configuration file. I should also make some changes there.

My problem :  my web provider does not allow access to the Apache configuration file. So I have no way to make these changes. Is there another way to correct the paths?

here is my .htaccess which is in de publicFolder

```
  # Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you provide code from your .htaccess file?

Comment: Of course, i added it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your application entry point for your apache web server is set to `/mywebsite` and not `/mywebsite/public` as required by the standard `.htaccess` file.
Since you don't have access to your web server settings, just move your `.htaccess` file from `/mywebsite/public` to the root of your site `/mywebsite` and replace the content with this:

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /public/index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

---

You also need to change the `base_path` parameter of the Asset component(if used) so that the resources are loaded correctly

Add to `config/packages/framework.yaml` file new base path:

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_path: /public
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This works fine, now i can navigate through my site with the righ paths. The little problem now: All my css/js files like bootstrap etc are now incorrectly linked. They are in the public-Folder. "public/css" "public/js"...

I use the asset-package so all paths are relative to my folder public. 
For example i  embed a logo like this "src="{{asset('img/mymlogo.svg')}}"
where do I have to start to fix this error? 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So i just put an public/ in front of each of my links to point to the right file. I hope this is they right way. 
If there is a better/easier way feel free to reply. Otherwise the thread can be closed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LittleEast Forgot to include this in the answer. I added a solution, try it. I think this is better practice

Comment: Excuse my late reply. I finally got around to making the changes. Everything works perfectly. Thank you very much!